# How to set a FragmentList in a NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-listfragment

I basically followed some tutorials on how to create a fragment list and how to make use of a navigation drawer. Here is what those elements look like.

**ListFragment:** https://youtu.be/GgUKTzMmxIs

**NavigationDrawer:** https://youtu.be/6SrKOBV_hx8

The problem is that I don't want a set list of elements on my navigation drawer I want it to be dinamic so I can retrieve objects from an API, list those objects on my navigation drawer and be able to see that list of objects and scroll through it. Navigation drawer has a property called menu which can use a menu xml resoruce file to fill itself with elements. What I'm trying to do is basically that but with a ListFragment instead of a menu.xml but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can modify the menu in a `NavigationView` programmatically. That is, you don't have to pre-define everything in the XML. Here's a link to a basic example I'd put together previously, if it'll help: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11M6pW1S7jR63bsO6OBu_n1pQqwIdZ0du/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for answering, I'll try that and see if it works with the objects retrieved from my API.

Answer (score 0):

How to set a FragmentList in a NavigationDrawer?
Follow my code you easily create set of Fragment in NavigationDrawer

- First create **manu resource directory** and create **manu.XML** file in it.
  [when click on first item shown fragment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AllSH.jpg).
  [when ckick on secon item shownfragment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlDoO.jpg).
  [when click on third item shown fragment 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yslmy.jpg).

**> **manu.XML:****

- i have create 3 tab for 3 Fragment.

  ```
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_home"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
       android:title="@string/home"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_call"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_call_24"
       android:title="@string/call"/>
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
       android:title="@string/search"/>
  ```
- create fragment do you need.
  **MainActivity.class**

  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ```
       private BottomNavigationView bnv;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bnv=(BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

       //app start thata j home fragme t load kri lesu
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

       bnv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
               //first apne ek temparary fragment create krsu e fragmnent ma jyare item click krse tyare tema
               // baki na fragment ne replace kri dese
               // md jaml -> https://youtu.be/Q3WtyqMBZ8c

               Fragment temp = new Fragment();

               switch(item.getItemId())
               {
                   case R.id.menu_home : temp = new HomeFragment();
                   break;
                   case R.id.menu_call : temp = new CallFragment();
                   break;
                   case R.id.menu_search : temp = new SearchFragment();
               }
               //have temp fragment ne main layout na fragment ma replace kri desu
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,temp).commit();
               return true;
           }
       });
   }
  ```

**activity_main.XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="#E0DBEB"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```